# Как сделать класс-обертку простейшим способом?

Tags: java, ооп, intellij-idea

Работаю в IntelliJ IDEA CE.

Хочу сделать обертку для org.slf4j.Logger, работающую следующим образом:

- методы группы `info` класс обрабатывает самостоятельно и перенаправляет внутреннему экземпляру Logger, получаемому через конструктор обертки
- все остальные методы просто перенаправляет.

Возможно, проще наследовать, но этот вариант мне не подходит по отдельным причинам.

Вручную прописывать все полсотни методов достаточно долго. Подозреваю, что это можно сделать одним-двумя хитрыми рефакторингами, но не нахожу точного способа. Существует ли он?

Comment: Думаю, стоит описать полную задачу. Скорее всего, требуется обработка логов, а не внедрение в логгер.

Comment: @Etki: я хочу сделать логгер, который будет кое-что писать в файл, причем в собственном формате.

Comment: Эм, не проще ли объявить его (FileAppender) в конфигурации и скормить ему нужный формат?

Comment: @Etki: возможно, проще. Насколько я понимаю, новая версия называется [WriterAppender.](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/WriterAppender.html)

Comment: Какая библиотека используется для логгирования, Logback? (slf4j, грубо говоря, предоставляет услуги проксирования)

Comment: @Etki: вроде как там `org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerFactory`, создающая их же `Logger`.

Comment: Насколько понял из своего небольшого опыта, SLF4J - не больше, чем обертка, проксирующая вызовы своих классов к конкретной библиотеке - commons-logging, log4j, logback. Конкретно одну из последних трех и надо конфигурировать.

Answer (score 1):

> Вручную прописывать все полсотни методов достаточно долго.

А если воспользоваться рефлексией и сгенерировать нужный код по всем методам?

Или даже просто собрать список прототипов методов и заменой по регулярному выражению преобразовать к функциям, вызывающим методы логгера.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с @Etki, самый прямой способ - добавить новый Appender и подцепить его, в этом случае ничего не потребуется в рабочей системе переделывать.